# Slider controls not showing in CDF deployed to wolfram cloud

Tags: manipulate, gui-construction, wolfram-cloud

When I run my CDF from CDFPlayer or Mathematica I see all additional controls (fast forward, play, pause, etc) when `Appearance->"Open"` is usede.g.:

```
Manipulate[x, {x, 0, 1, Appearance -> "Open"}]
```

When the same CDF is published to the Wolfram Cloud, I find that the controls are not present:

[image: CDF with no controls showing]

What is wrong?

Answer (score 3):

It seems to be a small bug in one of recent cloud releases. It used to work correctly.

The good news is that you can fix this by adding `AppearanceElements->All` or whatever subset you want:

[image]

I already reported this problem.

Comment: Thanks.  I will give it a try.  I do appreciate the feedback.